# jquery and ajax conflict - Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, jquery

ok Here is my issue: I am using Joomla 1.6,

I have a Ajax JS to display the slide how on my site located: [www.dhwnj.com](http://www.dhwnj.com) The Jquery script i am using when enabled stops my slide show from working so I tried using the No conflict script but I do not know if I am using it correctly :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this‐>baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery.metadata.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this‐>baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this‐>baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("jquery.maphilight.js").hide();
     });
   // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
    $('_class.noobSlide.packed.js').hide();
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo this->baseurl; ?>/templates/
<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/_class.noobSlide.packed.js" >
</script>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: what is that? would you mind cleaning up that code a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Prototype can't work together with Mootools and Mootools is loaded on your page (probably directly by Joomla)

Maybe here's the reason behind your problem...

Comment: Am I blind or is there no system plugin for mootools

Comment: Actually (if my memory is ok) Mootools is used by Joomla! for its backend and for all the DHTML/Ajax stuff (for example, when you add a WYSIWYG on one of your page). So no, there is no system plugin... it's a kind of core mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery after mootools. You can ensure mootools is looaded first by this code (use it in the module or in the view of a component)

```
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
$doc = &JFactory::getDocument();
....
$doc->addScript( "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" );
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery.noConflict();'); 
$doc->addScriptDeclaration(" 
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       alert('jo');
    });"
 );
```

This is code for joomla 1.5, don't know if the functions are the same in 1.6.